# XML layout in android image overlay

Tags: android

```
 <LinearLayout>
                    android:id="@+id/row2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ImageView1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/card1" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ImageView2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/cardshadow"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

i have tried this code  and works properly any suggestions ?? the output is image exactly lies below the images.. i expect to place image slightly below the image1

Comment: I don't think that this `<LinearLayout>` "works properly". You are prematurely closing the `LinearLayout` tag

Comment: **If** you want to add some margin (as far as I understood from your poorly phrased question), give a marginTop to the image on bottom **and/or** a marginBottom to the image on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your XMlfile with

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/row2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/card1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/cardshadow" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for your answers!!! it working fine in graphical layout in ide but not works in android sdk....

Comment: and how to center the image ... i need to center the 1stimage..???

Comment: Add android:gravity="center" in Relative Layout,
See my updated ans

Comment: <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/card1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/cardshadow" />
not

Comment: not working android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" and gravity:center.....any other answers...????

Comment: if its working  then select as mark ans

Comment: and another one how to set height between two tablerow

Comment: post your whole layout file

Answer (score 0):

**Use this in layout tag**

android:orientation="vertical"